# POSTing to a nodejs express backend with mongoose is failing

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I am trying to use this function to call a node.js express backend and create a user.  The function I am using on the frontend is below and the back end is [this](https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-boilerplate).  I have not made any changes to it other than to add a single field to the mongoose schema.

```
    let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
        let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/v1/auth/register", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
            email: "test@aol.com",
            password: "test1234",
            name: "test",
            //libraryCardId: "1234asdf",
            // mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
            }),
        });
        let resJson = await res.json();
        if (res.status === 200) {
            setName("");
            setEmail("");
            setMessage("User created successfully");
        } else {
            setMessage("Some error occured");
        }
        } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

I am able to get it working on Postman by using

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "email": "test123@aol.com",
    "password": "asdf1234"
}
```

as a JSON string with the JSON setting, but when I insert that as the JSON string hardcoded (see above) it fails the mongoose validator saying that there is no name, email or password.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: error: POST /v1/auth/register 400 - 1.528 ms - message: "email" is required, "password" is required, "name" is required

Comment: Can you add this setting in fetch? `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the content type is application/json in the fetch.

```
let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/v1/auth/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: 'test@aol.com',
        password: 'test1234',
        name: 'test',
        //libraryCardId: "1234asdf",
        // mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
    }),
});
```